# Mysql replace all id's to make a correct sequence

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment, increment

I was wondering if it's possible in mysql to reassign auto incremented ID's so that they will follow eachother up.

Currently I have deleted rows and because of that my ID's are as follow

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 8
- 9
- 14

Is it possible to run a query that will replace all id's with autoincrement again? So that the excisting rows will be

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6

Comment: No, don't mess with the auto-incrment. What do you need it for?

Comment: This is a frequent question,but the answer is that you dont need to.Gaps are not a probelm in the primary key.

Comment: Damn, I searched but couldn't find anything, BTW you guys are quick. I personally don't find it an issue but a client/colleague of mine insists on using the row ID to show in the CMS instead of just adding the numbers based on $i in the iteration of the loop. No idea why but I thought, if he insists we'll just do it =')

Comment: and the answer is not possible till u are using auto-increment.

Comment: Yes aesthetically its ugly,but think about it;everytime you delete something,you need to fill the gaps.And what if you have millions or more rows?

Comment: I completely agree! I'm sure it is possible with a lot of iteration in PHP and blabla but i'll just show him this and tell him it's impossible :) Im glad this is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done via phpMyAdmin:

- On your id column, remove the auto-increment setting
- Delete your primary key in Structure > indexes
- Create a new column future_id as primary key, auto_increment
- Browse your table and verify that the new increments correspond to what you're expecting
- Drop your old id column
- Rename the future_id column to id
- Move the new id column via Structure > Move columns

Comment: Can't upvote yet, need 4 more reputation but this helped. thanks!